# How can I know that an HTTP response is a response to HEAD request?

Tags: http, http-headers

Let's say I see an HTTP response with its header.

How do I know if it is a response to a `HEAD` request?

[RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.2.1) states that if `200 OK` is the status of the response, it should contain a message body only if it's not a response to a `HEAD` request. So I need to know if it is a response to a HEAD.

Do I have to keep a state and remember whether it is a response to a `HEAD` or is it possible to know that only from the response fields?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? You answered yourself if the response you see is 200 and have no body it's an answer to a HEAD. For others code it's another problem but please clarify your goal

Comment: What I try to do is to see if I should expected a body or not when I parse the HTTP response.

Comment: This question is Very relevant when implementing a reverse proxy. There doesn't seem to be any other way as to keep a state. Since the response to head MAY contain content-encoding:chunked header even if there's no body for response to head - through state only the proxy know that it's not supposed to wait for additional body ex. In order to do some data mangling.

Answer (score 1):

To allow you to see how the responses differ, you can use telnet:

```
> telnet myserver 80
> GET / HTTP/1.0

> telnet myserver 80
> HEAD / HTTP/1.0
```

...but as [radius](https://serverfault.com/users/9503/radius) commented, you appear to have answered your own question; if you get code 200 in response, with no body, assume it's a response to a HEAD request.

Comment: See my response to @radius comment

Answer (score 1):

As RFC 2616 tell, HTTP 1.1 is stateless, so you could do the job without keeping state (even if it's probably easier).
I don't see why you need to know if there is a body or not, you could just read data and see if there is data after the header or not.

Comment: The quote you gave from RFC 2616 is irrelevant since I've asked about a body in the response and not about a body in the request.

Comment: You're right, my bad!